# Burninate [spelling]

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms, retagging

[spelling](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spelling) is redundant. It should be a synonym of [orthography](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/orthography).

Answer (score 2):

I do not have an opinion for or against deletion of tag [spelling](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spelling), but for your information, the word “[orthography](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthography)” often includes not only spelling but also punctuation.

Comment: But is that a *useful* distinction for tagging? We do have [tag:punctuation].

Comment: @Mechanical snail: I am not sure if this distinction is useful for tagging.  I thought that your post is suggesting that existence of the tags [orthography] and [spelling] immediately makes one of them redundant, and I pointed out that it is not immediate because they can refer to different sets of questions.